# Username as variable in SSH with Perl

Tags: perl, variables, ssh

in my Perl Script I would like to connect to a machine via

```
my $result = `ssh $user@machine`;
```

where $user is the username on the current machine. However this does obviously not work, as Perl recognizes the whole string as one variable. So, is there any other way to use a variable in the username when connecting over SSH?

I have seen that there is a SSH Perl module, however I would like to avoid using additional modules if there is another solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: how helpful it is1

Answer (score 3):

Escape sigil Luke:

```
my $result = `ssh $user\@machine`;
```

There is not array `@machine`, isn't?

Backticks are [Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). (I recommend using generic `qx{}` version over customary backticks.) It interpolates (unless you use `qx''`) content so it interpolates `@machine` as a content of `machine` array. It separates members by a content of `$"` variable which is space by default. If you don't have `@machine` variable defined and there is not `use strict;` it is interpolated as an empty string and without warning if there is not `use warnings;` or `-W` parameter provided.

Comment: No, thats just the syntax of how to connect to a remote machine in ssh.

Comment: @Alex, >>>"However this does obviously not work, as Perl recognizes the whole string as one variable." - using '\' before @(escaping) is the way of making Perl to not see it as an array.

Comment: @Alex Without `use strict;` backtick expands `@machine` into content of array `@machine` even it doesn't exist so result is an empty string. If there would be some content in `@machine` it would be inserted there. Try `perl -e'my @a = qw(foo bar baz); print \`echo @a\`'`

Answer (score 3):

> *Perl recognizes the whole string as one variable.*

No, that's not the problem. The problem is that in addition to parsing `$user` as a variable, and it parses `@machine` as a variable too.

It's simply a question of escape special characters.

```
my $result = `ssh $user\@machine`;
```

---

If the problem really was that you needed to communicate the end of a variable, you can use curlies.

```
my $count = 4;
my $item = 'book';
print("$count $items\n");     # XXX
print("$count ${item}s\n");   # 4 books
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
my $result = `ssh ${user}\@machine`;

when you have multiple variables you can use {} to say that they are different
like: ${user1}_${user2}

Comment: That's only necessary if the character immediately after the variable name is a valid variable character.  `@` is not valid anywhere except at the beginning of an array variable (or slice, or array dereference, etc), so there is no need to wrap `user` in `{}` in this case.  It won't hurt anything, sure, but no need to confuse the actual issue, which is the `@` needing to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This should work Alex:

```
`ssh "${user}"@"${machine}"`;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape "@" in the string, as its a array and use double quotes around variable user.

Try:

```
my $result = `ssh "$user"\@machine`;
```

Comment: The quotes are completely unnecessary.  They serve exactly 0 purpose.